# Thread safe tracking in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I found a lot of questions and information that DbContext is not thread safe. But examples in such questions contains `SaveChanges` call that is used by several threads. What about the next example:

```
someCollection1.AsParallel().ForAll(item => { item.SomeField = 0; dbContext.Update(item); })
someCollection2.AsParallel().ForAll(item => { item.SomeField = 0; dbContext.Update(item); })
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

As I understand the row `dbContext.Update(item)` makes `dbContext` tracks `item` for update. `SaveChanges` is called by the only one thread. Is this ok that several threads access to `Update` to track?

Comment: Even if this works, it's not going to make anything faster. Calling the `Update` method is virtually instantaneous anyway.

Comment: `SaveChanges` will generate the UPDATE statements and execute them. All those `AsParallel` calls simply waste time

Comment: that seems *remarkably* likely to be brittle; the only way to know for sure is to know whether `Update` is **documented** as being thread-safe, and that `SomeField` (which I'm guessing is actually a property) doesn't have on-change side-effects that are harmful, but... this seems like a terrible idea. Since [the docs don't mention thread safety](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-2.1), the correct assumption is that `Update` makes no guarantees of being thread-safe

Comment: All questions that ask for "parallel" updates hide a performance issue unrelated to parallelism. Most often it's missing indexes, bad queries, or using an ORM in ways they aren't supposed to be used. If you want to update multiple rows for example, an `UPDATE Table1 set SomeField=0 Where ID IN (whatever)` is orders of magnitude faster and more scaleable than loading all rows to the client and then sending them back. It won't even need a transaction as `UPDATE` is atomic

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos re "missing indexes, bad queries" etc... the code shown doesn't touch the database inside the parallel piece, just the object tracker; but agree with you 100% on the direct SQL version - personally I'd delimit the ids and use `STRING_SPLIT` (to prevent parameter count / query-plan explosion), but there's lots of ways of doing it

Comment: @MarcGravell pieces in a puzzle. The code will result in N `UPDATE ... SET Field=0 Where ID=...` operations. If the OP feels the need for parallel updates, it means there are a lot of them. I'd even guess this is an attempt to use an ORM for ETL work and specifically, a batch update. The fast and easy way would be to load all IDs into a staging table  and execute a single UPDATE query.

Comment: @MarcGravell my preference is ObjectReader->SqlBulkCopy to load the staging table, `UPDATE target Set... FROM target inner join staging on ...`. Now, if only there was an easier way to extract field names from ObjectReader ....

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos IIRC table-valued-parameters use *mostly* the same code-path as `SqlBulkCopy`, but without requiring a target table; I just wish that SQL Server shipped with simple vector types burned in (perhaps even using generics), so "vector::int" would be a table-valued-parameter with a single `int` column called `value`, for example

Comment: @user190794 No one still has answered your question. Is Tracking object thread-safe or what?

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft's docs (see [Entity Framework Core: Asynchronous Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/async)), EF Core does not support running multiple parallel operations on the same `DbContext` instance.  Thus, in order to run multiple parallel operations on the same database you need to have a dedicated `DbContext` instance per thread.

Comment: The question's code doesn't perform any database operations in parallel. [Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-2.1)  just registers an object for change tracking and saving. It's the single `SaveChanges` command that generates and executes all SQL statements

Comment: In any case, the only thing that can increase with parallel modifications is wait times, as each connection will try to execute the same statement on the same table, indexes etc. They'll all require the same *exclusive* locks on the table, resulting in blocking

Comment: Given the repeated attempt to set the same field, the OP would get far better performance *and* parallel execution with an `UPDATE Table1 SET SomeField=0 where ID in (....)`.